# What is this style or technique called I can't find any info about it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, style-identification, illustrator-effects

I tried to imitate this style, I used filters like Posterize, Threshold, Cut Out, a combination of filters, played with levels, curves, gradients... Nothing. I tried brushes to just be close to that effect or style I couldn't. If anyone know what is this technique or style please help me identify it or at least know what's going on on those pics.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't tell you if this technique has a *name* as such. You are certainly on the right track with *Posterize* and *Threshold*, but I believe the main "effect" used here is the color mode *Indexed Color*.

Just applying an effect won't be enough to achieve this style though. The images you post have other things in common: they all have high contrast, lots of black and white, mostly on a black background. And of course they all have a dark horror theme.

Here is a method to get you started. You might have to tweak things and apply other filters depending on the images you have.

---

My starting point is this image of a cute bighorn sheep (sorry, but I couldn't quickly find a fitting free horror image):

[image]

(Public Domain, by Jean Beaufort, https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/)

I use *Camera Raw Filter* to make the image monochrome and give it a harsh look with lots of contrast.

In the *Basic* tab, I use the following settings:

[image]

I also turn down the *Aquas*, *Blues* and *Purples* in the *B&W Mixer* tab:

[image]

I use *Quick Selection Tool* to select the background, give it a bit of feathering and use levels to make the background completely black.

Now I have an image fitting for applying the actual effect:

[image]

I enter *Image > Mode > Indexed Color* and set it up like this:

[image]

You could also try to set *Dither* to *Noise*, but for this I like how *Diffusion* allows us to lower the *Amount* of dithering so we get some larger areas of each color.

In the *Forced* dropdown, I choose *Custom* and define the 3 colors I want: black RGB(0,0,0), white RGB(255,255,255) and gray RGB(128,128,128):

[image]

When I click *OK* to change the color mode, I get this result (click to view it at 100%):

[image]

Now I can enter *Image > Mode > Color Table* and change the gray color to another color:

[image]

And the result looks pretty good in my opinion:

[image]

Again, remember to view the image at 100% or larger to be able to see the actual pixels:

[image]

You can convert back to RGB mode to be able to make further modifications. For example, you might like to apply *Dust & Scratches* filter to make the texture more chunky:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you're a lifesaver

Comment: @tofemo9741, you are welcome! And welcome to GDSE!

Comment: I'd +10 this if I could. Nice... so rare anyone thinks to tweak the color table `:)`

Comment: Thanks @Scott. Actually it's an important detail because just choosing a red color to begin with will give a much more dull result.

Comment: I think always the background color is black then your build over it.

Comment: @tofemo9741, well most of the examples you show are black t-shirts. It might be printed with the black as transparent. I didn't mention, that you can of course combine images using this technique. Might require a bit of attention to get nice aliased (non-blurred, jagged) contours. Perhaps using *Dissolve* blend mode can be helpful.

Comment: You can also sprinkle those brush patterns later around the subject and behind it, if you want. And since you asked, I think it's called "Retro" design? @tofemo9741

Comment: @Wolff Mostly influenced by 80s horror movie posters. But the trick to get it like you've did in this tutorial, isn't easy to find even your tutorial is the only one I can find. Thank you again for this amazing helpful post. I hope everyone can learn something out of it.

Comment: @Vikas, yes to sprinkling! I'm sure the posted examples have required some additional manual painting. It's "retro" for sure, but so are all other styles mimicking techniques of the past.

Comment: `:)` This is **not** what is I would refer to as "retro". I'd say it's closer to "trash polka", or "Limited palette HDR" than it is retro.

Comment: Additional tip: Select Grayscale mode play with levels go back to RGB then use Indexed Mode. If you want to do it fast instead of playing a bit with Camera RAW.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the Noise Dither pattern you get when converting to Indexed Colour Mode, with a low number of colours.

For example

[image]

zoomed detail

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for thank you so much.